# Differences between 32- and 64-bit C++ compiler in VS 2005

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, 32bit-64bit

I'm going to port a large C++-Project to x64 (some parts of it are written about 15 years ago) and I found that the 64-bit compiler does not support inline assembly, so I have to change the code. I would like to know if there are more differences or incompatibilities between both compilers. Or the better question would be are there parts of 32-compiler which 64-compiler does not suport.

Comment: The sizeof has changed. And you may encounter naughty problems related to that.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. As I understand the primitive types did not changed. Can you give an example?

Comment: On 32 bits systems (at least on Linux), `sizeof(int)` = `sizeof(long)` = `sizeof(void*)` = 4 bytes. On 64 bits systems, that is no more the case, so casts may lose information.... And you might have alignment issues too....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relevant articles:

- [The forgotten problems of 64-bit programs development](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0010/)
- [Seven Steps of Migrating a Program to a 64-bit System](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0042/)
- [Collection of Examples of 64-bit Errors in Real Programs](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0065/)

Comment: Thanks! I take a look on it.